# Anchor a view at the front always when visibility changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a frameLayout `full_view` whose visibility is gone when first rendered. Also I have a visible RelativeLayout `bottom_view` which is aligned to bottom with a parent.

I would like to place this `bottom_view` always at the front, whenever the visibility of `full_view` is changed. However, when `full_view` is set to visible, `bottom_view` gets hidden. Is there any way I can anchor `bottom_view` at the front always using xml?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/full_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `bottom_view` should be showing at top of `full_view` with this layout . What else you want ? can u add an expected output image ? Anchor is something else usually we call a view is anchor which is half overlapping other view.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/full_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_view"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

add `android:layout_above="@id/bottom_view"` in your FrameLayout